# Create Macro With Several Variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have several worksheets with similar code, so I'd like to turn it into a macro. My only problem is that there are several variables. So at certain points the code looks like this:

```
Dim Msg1 As String
Dim Msg2 As String

Public Sub ListBox1_LostFocus()
ListBox1.Height = 15
With ListBox1
Msg1 = "'"
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Msg1 = Msg1 & .List(i) & "','"
        End If
    Next i
End With
Msg1 = Left(Msg1, Len(Msg1) - 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R3", "R3") = Msg1
End Sub
```

and so on. How can I pass in a new value for Msg1, Msg2, Msg3 for each worksheet?

Comment: perhaps you should elaborate on your question a bit more, this routine builds a comma seperated list from selected values and stores it in a cell, if you want to change the list select other entries

Comment: How do I create a macro to substitute values for Msg1 for each page? So if this is the code for sheet1, how do I copy that for sheet2 (without replacing each variable)? I'd like one code that I can edit and have the changes affect all the sheets.

Comment: I don't want to change the list, I want to change the Msg part.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and put gathermessage below into that module

```
public function gathermessage(list as listbox) as string
    'generate your message
    gathermessage = msg
end function
```

to use:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R3", "R3") = gathermessage(listbox1)
```

I believe it would be a good exercise for you to work out the details.